# Swiftui Cannot mix up a UIViewController + Removing Complier ( Swift Playgrounds ) problem in ios15

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem that i fixed for 2 days still cannot solve. My project is like this.

```
struct ContentView: View{
     var body: some View{
           Controller()
     }
}

struct Controller: UIViewControllerRespresentable{
     func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> Contro {
          let viewController = Contro()
          //additional setup
          return viewController
     }
     func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: Contro, context: Context) {
         //update Content
     }
}

class Contro: UIViewController{
     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
          let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rename Subject", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
          alert.addTextField{ value in
              value.placeholder = "subject name"
              value.returnKeyType = .continue
          }
          alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
          alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: { _ in
            guard let fields = alert.textFields, fields.count == 1 else {
                return
            }
            guard let texts = fields[0].text, !texts.isEmpty else {
                return
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(texts, forKey: "RenamedSubjectName")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.0001){
                self.dismiss(animated: true)
            }

            present(alert, animated: true)
        }
     }
}
```

And the compiler load and load and say: cannot build app, the compiler cannot check the error now, try to break it up to sub-expresstions

So how to solve? I will thank everyone who helped me :D

Comment: Sorry, i tried the code but still don’t work. I don’t know why, i will edit my post now.

Comment: `control` should be the same as your `ViewController` name same as in the answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it still becoming the same thing - error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Controller` with this:

```
struct Controller: UIViewControllerRespresentable{
     func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> Contro {
          let viewController = Contro()
          //additional setup
          return viewController
     }
     func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: Contro, context: Context) {
         //update Content
     }
}
```

You should use the name of your `UIVIewController` instead of `ViewController` same as `contro`.

Comment: The compiler loaded for a long time in my Ipad ( swift playgrounds ), and still return errors

Comment: make sure to copy paste the code in the answer, all `contro` should start with capital c`.

Comment: Oh! Yea! That’s the error!

Comment: If I answered your question, could you please mark the answer as accepted using the checkmark button> Have a great day!

Comment: Ok :D You fixed my problems a lot, I will not forget your all helpings! :D